# @EnableResourceServer not available in springboot application

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2, spring-rest, spring-security-ldap

The resource server is not detected in the sprign application.Not able to get the reason behind.

Please help on this

This is my pom

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.test.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>admin-service</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <name>admin-service</name>
    <description>MS Admin Service</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Hoxton.SR7</spring-cloud.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <maven.version>3.0.0</maven.version>
        <maven.build.timestamp.format>yyyyMMddHHmmss</maven.build.timestamp.format>
        <maven.compiler.source>${java.version}</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>${java.version}</maven.compiler.target>
        <swagger.version>2.8.0</swagger.version>
        <sonar-maven-plugin.version>3.2</sonar-maven-plugin.version>
        <jacoco-maven-plugin.version>0.8.0</jacoco-maven-plugin.version>
        <cxf.version>3.3.0</cxf.version>
        <spring-cloud-services.version>2.0.3.RELEASE</spring-cloud-services.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.zxing</groupId>
            <artifactId>core</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.zxing</groupId>
            <artifactId>javase</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-hystrix</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-ribbon</artifactId>
        </dependency> 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-openfeign</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-sleuth</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-aws-context</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mariadb.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>mariadb-java-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.symantec.scanengine</groupId>
            <artifactId>SymJavaAPI</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.pivotal.spring.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-services-starter-service-registry</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.pivotal.spring.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-services-starter-config-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>${swagger.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>${swagger.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-text</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-csv</artifactId>
            <version>1.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
            <version>${oauth.version}</version>
        </dependency>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.pivotal.spring.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-services-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud-services.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.sonarsource.scanner.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${sonar-maven-plugin.version}</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${jacoco-maven-plugin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>pre-unit-test</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <destFile>${project.build.directory}/jacoco.exec</destFile>
                            <propertyName>surefireArgLine</propertyName>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>post-unit-test</id>
                        <phase>test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>report</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <dataFile>${project.build.directory}/jacoco.exec</dataFile>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.reporting.outputDirectory}/jacoco</outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        
    </build>
    
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>unit-test</id>
            <build>
                <pluginManagement>
                    <plugins>
                        <plugin>
                            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                            <configuration>
                                <argLine>${surefireArgLine}</argLine>
                                <excludes>
                                    <exclude>**/*Integration*.java</exclude>
                                </excludes>
                                <includes>
                                    <include>**/*Test*.java</include>
                                </includes>
                            </configuration>
                        </plugin>
                    </plugins>
                </pluginManagement>
            </build>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>integration-test</id>
            <build>
                <pluginManagement>
                    <plugins>
                        <plugin>
                            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                            <configuration>
                                <argLine>${surefireArgLine}</argLine>
                                <includes>
                                    <include>**/*Test*.java</include>
                                </includes>
                            </configuration>
                        </plugin>
                    </plugins>
                </pluginManagement>
            </build>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

</project>
```

@EnableResourceServer is not able to detect and gives cannot resolve error.

```
@Slf4j
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer //-- cannot resolve  
public class GatewayConfiguration extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        log.info("");
        http.authorizeRequests().
            antMatchers("/login/**").
            permitAll().
            antMatchers("/**").
            authenticated();
    }    
}
```

if i write a simple application

@EnableResourceServer is detected from

```
enter code here
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.5RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>`enter code here`
```

Please help on how to resolve this and enable resource server

Comment: I'd suggest you to no longer use that project since it's deprecated, see here: https://spring.io/projects/spring-security-oauth . Use directly Spring Security 5 which provides a full Oauth2 support.

Answer (score 0):

updating from
<spring-cloud.version>Hoxton.SR7</spring-cloud.version>
<spring-cloud-services.version>2.0.3RELEASE</spring-cloud-services.version>
to

<spring-cloud.version>Hoxton.SR8</spring-cloud.version>
<spring-cloud-services.version>2.2.3.RELEASE</spring-cloud-services.version>

updating these 2 versions resolved my issue